# MS Excel - Google Docs - Using possible if statements?

Tags: excel, google-docs

I have clients that spend money on a daily basis. I need to be able to keep their average daily spend as close to their budget as possible. I want to be able to add a function/formula that will add up their daily spend, subtract from their monthly budget, then divide the leftover money based on the number of days left in the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a column of dates listed in column A for example, and the spending per day listed in column B, and the monthly budget in a cell, say D1, for example during the month of March then you could set up this formula in another cell to determine the target spending per day in the future:

Remaining budget would be

```
= D1 - SUM(B1:B31)
```

Remaininng days in the month would be

```
= A31-TODAY()
```

So then the answer would be

```
=(D1 - SUM(B1:B31))/(A31-TODAY())
```

Comment: I currently have my dates in B1 through Af1
The daily spend in B3 through AF3
Monthly budget in AH3
I came up with this:
=(AH3 - SUM(B3:AF3))/(B1:AF1-TODAY())
Not working please help...

Comment: Why do you have B1:AF1 - TODAY()? You only need AF1 - TODAY() in the denominator. (The difference between the current date and the last day in the month.)